# stop setting onclick event for asp:LinkButton if no OnClick event was explicitly defined

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I setup a default setting so that if I do not set an OnClick (i.e the asp.net OnClick attribute) explicitly for an asp:LinkButton tag, it will not render an onclick(html attribute for javascript) attribute client side? By default, asp.net adds an onclick='doPostBack....' for the LinkButton.

Case for use:

There is a LinkButton tag on the page. For this page, if the user has one friend, I only want to run client side code if the button is clicked and would not for any reason want to make a post back. If the user has more than one friend I would want a click to trigger a postback.

Solutions that include the following are not helpful:

1. Using any asp.net Ajaxtoolkit
2. Dynamically switching the control type (i.e. if friends == 1 use a asp:Hyperlink) 
   -I want to avoid this because it is not scalable. There might be many cases where I want an asp:Link tag to do a postback or to not do a postback depending on the user context or user attributes
3. Using OnClientClick (I am using jQuery would like to avoid this)

Solution that would be helpful if possible:

If I could see server side at runtime whether an OnClick event was explicitly set on an asp:LinkButton tag, this would solve my problem, too. any ideas?

Comment: well I have answered my question. But I wanted to add an even quicker and simpler solution, use the Enabled property of the button to disable it without having to actually remove or reattach a click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1129106.aspx

This link explains how to see server side at runtime whether an OnClick event was explicitly set using reflection

Answer (score 0):

How about rather than dynamically switching the controls (as you mentioned is a solution you don't want), you could *always* use an `asp:HyperLink` and set the `NavigateUrl` property to redirect your page back to itself with a query string of some sort indicating what was clicked.

If you don't want the post to happen at all, simply leave the `NavigateUrl` property blank.

Of course, this will be pretty worthless if the rest of the page is dependent on ViewState and such.

Comment: eh, I am not crazy about that solution and also the asp:Hyperlink also does not implement IButton interface therefore it cannot be used as the default button for asp:Panel or form which is handy for the old hit the enter key click. Thanks though.